# hiccup 1.0.0-beta1 error

Tags: clojure, compojure, hiccup

I'm creating a compojure project using hiccup-1.0.0-beta1. I get the following stack trace when I run `lein ring server-headless`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: defelem does not exist
at clojure.core$refer.doInvoke(core.clj:3287)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4781)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:544)
at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:4892)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at hiccup.page_helpers$eval17$loading__4414__auto____18.invoke(page_helpers.clj:1)
at hiccup.page_helpers$eval17.invoke(page_helpers.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
```

Which is confusing to me, because the file `page_helpers.clj` no longer exists in hiccup:

```
$ jar tf lib/hiccup-1.0.0-beta1.jar 
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/hiccup/hiccup/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/hiccup/hiccup/pom.properties
project.clj
hiccup/compiler.clj
hiccup/core.clj
hiccup/def.clj
hiccup/element.clj
hiccup/form.clj
hiccup/middleware.clj
hiccup/page.clj
hiccup/util.clj
$
```

Also, my code doesn't even try to bring in page_helpers.clj:

```
(ns views.layout 
    (:require [app-config :as config])
    (:use hiccup.core)
    (:use hiccup.page)
    (:use hiccup.element))
```

Comment: reverted to 0.3.8 and (after fixing up the :use statements) the code works fine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same trouble.

I think you are using dev-dependency **lein-ring**. If you look in to your project/lib/dev folder, you'll see **hiccup 0.3.X jar** there. It is because the file **ring-devel jar** file uses old hiccup. I guess the cause to the problem is to do with the conflicts between these files. But I haven't figured out a way to get around this yet.

However, if you use *lein ring uberwar* to create a deployable file, that file works in another container (eg. tomcat) just fine.

Comment: in maven I can do dependency exclusions...I'm not a lein pro yet but I wonder if there's a way to exclude hiccup from lein-ring? But nice catch, that was bothering me...

Comment: This is how you exclude dependencies: 
:dev-dependencies [[lein-ring "0.5.4" :exclusions [hiccup]]]

But i'm still getting an error

Comment: As per this github issue https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup/issues/41#issuecomment-4423262, This will be fixed only in Ring 1.1